# How to compile and run openmpi code using jupyterhub

Tags: python, c, jupyter-notebook, mpi, jupyterhub

i am unable to load some of linux programming commands into jupyterhub, like mpicc, mpirun etc..
actually i want to run my openmpi code from jupyterhub.
From terminal i am able to run this code, but not from the notebook.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define  MASTER 0

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int   numtasks, taskid, len;
char hostname[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);
MPI_Get_processor_name(hostname, &len);
printf ("Hello from task %d on %s!\n", taskid, hostname);

if (taskid == MASTER)
   printf("MASTER: Number of MPI tasks is: %d\n",numtasks);
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

[image: mpi code]

Please guide me how to run mpi code from jupyterhub and how to load other linux command like module etc.

Regards,
Zain

Comment: fix your typo first

Comment: You typed `moudle list` in the notebook, not `module list`.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. i have tried with `module list` still i am getting same error. command  `!module list` and error message is `/usr/bin/sh: module: command not found`